# how can i create a new String in a get Method?(Java)

Tags: java

I have this code down below. I want if there is no other person in the row my getMother Method to create a new String or Person with the first name "Eva" and return this.
 With my code it doesn't work. I always get "null". How can i do this? pls help

```
public Person getMother() {
     if (mother == null) {
       Person p = new Person("Eva");
       }
       return mother;

   }
```

Comment: Your title, question, and code all say different things. I have no idea what you're trying to ask, but I would assume that @Adem got it correct.

Comment: how do you suppose to get not null with this piece of code???? Actually you are returning the same null value! Check you code again and loudly ask what it does and what it returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should initialize `mother`, not `p`:

```
public Person getMother() {
    if (mother == null) {
        mother = new Person("Eva");
    }
    return mother;
}
```

Comment: thx i will accept it when the "cooldown" is over ty